# Can I connect 64-bit MS Access to a 32-bit ODBC driver?

Tags: 64-bit, microsoft-access, 32-bit, odbc

I have (only) a 32-bit Ingres ODBC driver and 64-bit MS Access.  I want to create linked tables in Access that point to an Ingres database.

I know about needing to use `c:\windows\sysWOW64\odbcad32.exe` to create and manage 32-bit ODBC connections on a 64-bit machine.  But even doing this, and creating a 32-bit ODBC connection with a 32-bit driver, I get the error:

> The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application(#0)

when attempting to use the ODBC connection in 64-bit Access.

Is there any way to use a 32-bit ODBC driver with a 64-bit application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Is there any way to use a 32-bit ODBC driver with a 64-bit application?

No.

> You absolutely cannot mix 32bit application and 64bit driver (or
>   vice-versa).
>
> Basically, an ODBC driver is, typically, a dll (windows) or a shared
>   object (linux...) which is loaded by its parent application.
>
> All executables, dlls, etc that share the same process space must be
>   the same bit'ness...

Source [Can i use a 32 Bit ODBC Driver for my 64 Bit app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5635675/3536342), answer by [Garry M. Biggs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/692843/garry-m-biggs)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to connect using ODBC
I would suggest looking at an ODBC Bridge that would convert the ODBC connection from 32bit to 64bit
but the solution i have seen does cost around £1800